# Spacy Entity Ruler regex pattern not recognizing match

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I am using spacy entity ruler to build a custom ner for my domain. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler

I have some text and i want to extract entities from the text, however the words **could** contain a `#` or an `@` at the begining. Rather than creating a new pattern for each ive tried to give the regex pattern matcher a try.

https://repl.it/repls/WrithingHideousJavabeans

**Code**:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler


team_words = [{
  'id': '111',
  'name': "fnatic"
},{
  'id': '222',
  'name': "100 thieves"
}]

team_patterns = [{
  'label': 'TEAM',
  'pattern': [{'TEXT': {'REGEX': f"^(#|@?){w['name']}"}}], 
  'id': w['id']
} for w in team_words]

# { 'label': 'TEAM',  'pattern': "100 thieves",  'id': '222' }

nlp = English()
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = team_patterns

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)


# expect it to match 100 thieves but it does not
doc = nlp("text text text 100 thieves text text text")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_, ent.ent_id_) for ent in doc.ents])

## working however the # in #fnatic is not present in the ent.text output
doc = nlp("text text text #fnatic @fnatic fnatic text text text")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_, ent.ent_id_) for ent in doc.ents])

## expect it not to match but it does
doc = nlp("text text text fnatichello text text text")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_, ent.ent_id_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

**output**

```
[]
[('fnatic', 'TEAM', '111'), ('@fnatic', 'TEAM', '111'), ('fnatic', 'TEAM', '111')]
[('fnatichello', 'TEAM', '111')]
```

I have 3 problems with the result of the above code.

1. 100 thieves is simply not being matched when using the pattern text regex. I've tried to add a backslash to escape the " " but that did not work. It seems like its having a problem with the space? However if you do a simple pattern match it will work.
2. This one is mostly correct, it identifies all 3 words as entities. However the ent.text for `#fnatic` seems to be missing the hashtag.
3. I believe this is an issue with my regex, i need it to stop after my word e.g `fnatic` the word should end there. So this one should not match.

Comment: As for 3), you just need to use `$` at the end of the regex, `{'REGEX': fr"^[#@]?{w['name']}$"}}`. As for 1), `REGEX` only matches within a single token, `100 thieves` are two tokens.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey thanks for your reply Are you sure about 1) because if i use `
{ 'label': 'TEAM',  'pattern': "100 thieves",  'id': '222' }` it matches

Comment: Yeah, you are not using regex, if you use `team_patterns.append({ 'label': 'TEAM', 'pattern': [{'TEXT': {'REGEX': "100 thieves"}}],  'id': '222'})` it does not return `100 thieves` any longer. The same issue is with `#fnatic`: it is tokenized as two tokens, `'#', 'fnatic'`

Comment: Okay but i dont understand why setting a regex pattern to match upon as oppose to a non-regex pattern would cause it to tokenize it differently? How are you determining that?